# submit does not work on django 2.1 model form rendered manually with updateview

Tags: django

totally a new to django.

I have a modelform and have manually rendered it using the form fields so that I can use it with my CSS , however, form.as_p if used seems to save my data, if I use the manual form rendering and submit, nothing saves and wanted to know 
1) why the form.as_p works and my custom form fields will not work
2) the update view class , does it require the post method?

```
class CompanyUpdateView(UpdateView):
    template_name = 'inservice/company_update.html'
    form_class = CompanyForm
    model = CompanyInfo


    def get_object(self):
        pk_=self.kwargs.get("pk")
        return get_object_or_404(CompanyInfo,pk=pk_)


company_update.html
<form method="POST" action="">
    {% csrf_token %}


    <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class ="row mb-5">
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="custdiv">
                        <hr>
                        <h3>Company Information</h3>
                        <hr>
                        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <td>Company Name:</td>
                                <td>{{form.companyname}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone:</td>                         
                                <td> {{form.phone}} </td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Total Veh:</td>                         
                                <td>{{form.numberofcars}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Status:</td>                            
                                <td>{{form.status}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Address: </td>
                                <td>{{form.address}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Unit: </td>
                                <td>{{form.unitno}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>City:</td>
                                <td>{{form.city}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Province: </td>
                                <td>{{form.provincestate}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Country: </td>
                                <td>{{form.country}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Postal/Zip</td>
                                <td>{{form.postalcode}} </td>
                            </tr>   
                        </table>


    enter code here



                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="custdiv">
                    <hr aria-colcount="1">
                    <h3>System Information</h3>
                    <hr>
                    <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                        <tr>
                            <td>XDS Version</td>
                            <td>{{form.xdsversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>CallBack Version</td>
                            <td>{{form.callbackversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>SMS Version</td>
                            <td>{{form.smsversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>Ngate Version</td>
                            <td>{{form.ngateversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>XCD version</td>
                            <td>{{form.xcdccversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>FleetAPI Version</td>
                            <td>{{form.fleetapiversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IBS version</td>
                            <td>{{form.ibsversion}}</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>IBS Link</td>
                            <td>{{form.ibstestlink}}</td>
                        </tr>
                    </table>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col">
                    <div class="custdiv">
                        <hr>
                        <h3>Misc Information</h3>
                        <hr>

                        <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
                            <tr>
                                <td><strong>Info</strong></td>
                                <td>{{form.comments}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gate IPAddress</td>
                                <td>{{form.gateIP}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Gate Port</td>
                                <td>{{form.gatePort}}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Phone System</td>
                                <td>{{form.phonesystem}}</td>
                            </tr>

                        </table>

                    </div>

                </div>

        </div>
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-success" type="submit" name="Save"> <a class ="btn btn-warning" href="{%url 'inservice:company_list'%}">Home Changes</a>   
</form>
```

Comment: form.as_p means you are calling form as a paragraph, you can simply use {{form}} and add css to make that happen. For custom fields you need to call it by name.  2nd question, yes you need to add POST function, otherwise how the server will know you are updating the data in those fields.

Comment: Thank you ! so basically {{form}} would default it as a table form. but i would prefer to customize the look by using the custom form.xxx call . would you mind putting an example of the def post method? having abit of hard time on that..

Comment: you're not rendering the form errors in your template so if the form doesn't validate you'll never know why. How to properly render a form manually is documented (in the official doc and in a couple articles).

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers. Thank you. that was it. so basically I set the print {form.errors} and a couple of fields which I was not showing were not validated and hence fail to save the data to the dB. so I have to now make sure I have the form validation in place.